# Calculate variance of estimates in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, variance, regression-coefficients

I was wondering if there exist formulas or reliable approximations  (but not simulation or bootstrap based) to calculate the variance of the parameter estimates in logistic regression?

If my model is

$$ y\sim \operatorname{bern}(p) \quad \operatorname{logit}(p)= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1$$,

I would want to find for example:

$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta_1}),$$

where the parameter estimation is done by maximum likelihood. I know this might be difficult because the parameter estimation of parameters in logistic regression is done numerically and does not have a closed form and using standard errors might not be reliable.

Comment: The covariants matrix can be computed as follows https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/527109/why-the-standard-errors-of-logistic-regression-are-of-that-form/585181#585181